# Add entries to MANIFEST.MF during packaging from another Maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

We've created a Maven plugin to simplify creation of executable war files. The approach is similar to that described here: http://uguptablog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/embedded-jetty-executable-war-with.html. Our custom mojo does the work of the antrun plugin and unpack-dependencies steps, greatly reducing clutter and details a developer shouldn't need to worry about for a simple webapp.

The plugin is working fine, and the webapp POM looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.acme.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
```

What we'd like to do is remove the maven-war-plugin configuration, as it's only needed to write the Main-Class property into the manifest. Am struggling to see how to achieve this, but I can see two possible approaches:

- Somehow indicate to the regular war plugin from our mojo that extra manifest entries are needed. I don't know if this is even remotely possible
- Have our plugin extend the default war plugin. I don't know if this is possible because the war plugin is bound to the packaging/lifecycle, and I don't think you can affect this from within another plugin. Each project would have to customise the lifecycle, which defeats the object as it's much harder than the above configuration!

Any advice/help much appreciated.

Comment: What not creating the manifest file in your plugin yourself?

Comment: The standard war plugin will overwrite the custom one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the [achive configuration of the Maven War Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#archive) like the following:

But your plugin should be bound to the life cycle phase `generate-resources` to make sure your plugins runs before maven-war-plugin, cause the given pom means your plugin will run after maven-war-plugin.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestFile>target/xyz/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Furthermore i would suggest to use an [uptodate version of the plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and not such ancient version.

BTW: What about making [contributions to the maven-war-plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR) to support such things?

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your response but it doesn't really address the problem at hand. We are trying to remove the need for maven-war-plugin configuration completely. Using manifestFile instead of the mainClass approach in my example doesn't achieve that goal. Take your point about contributing though... it might come to that ;-)

Comment: Than your plugin must create the appropriate file plus the structure and you need to define your own life cycle and a separate packaging type to prevent interfere with maven-war-plugin....

Comment: Thanks I will look at that option. At least I know now there is no simpler way...

Answer (score 0):

`maven-war-plugin` (and also `maven-jar-plugin`) use [`Apache Maven Archiver`](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) to build output archive.

You can try to use [`Apache Maven Archiver`](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) in your plugin, you can see in `maven-war-plugin` [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-war-plugin-2.6/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/war/AbstractWarMojo.java?view=markup) how to do it.